# Comparing a Selected Index Combo Box to another Selected Index Combo Box

Tags: c#, selectedindex

Basically what I am trying to do, is compare the selected Index of two combo boxes in Win Forms. 
If ComboBoxA.SelectedIndex == 1 and, ComboBoxB.SelectedIndex == 1, I need to prevent that from happening, by changing ComboBoxB.SelectedIndex to 2.

I tried doing this through an If statement and couldn't get the results I was looking for.

```
  if (Northern.SelectedIndex == 1 && NorthernEnd.SelectedIndex == 1)
                NorthernEnd.SelectedIndex = 2;
```

However, I can't seem to get this to work. I am a beginner in C# working on my last assignment of the term.

Comment: In your code, you're not preventing. You're allowing it.

Comment: this should work, as you shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the event to prevent the action:

```
if (Northern.SelectedIndex == 1 && NorthernEnd.SelectedIndex == 1)
    e.Handled = true;
```

Here is the [MSDN ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled(v=vs.110).aspx).